# Apache2 Authentifiation with LDAP

Tags: ldap, apache2

I have a working LDAP Authentification with `<Directory>` but now I need the same with `<Location>`.

**working:**

```
<Directory /home/foo-bar/>
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "foo bar"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://www.foo.bar
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=bar
    AuthLDAPBindPassword foo
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

does nothing:

```
<Location /foo-bar/>
    DAV on
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "foo bar"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPUrl ldap://www.foo.bar
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=bar
    AuthLDAPBindPassword foo
    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The location works when I test it with allow only ip address 1.2.3.4 oder when i try a passwd-file, but nothing happens (= the browser shows the page) when I try the ldap authentification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<Location /railo-context/>
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Railo Admin"
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://www......
  AuthLDAPBindDN cn=admin,dc=....
  AuthLDAPBindPassword .....
  Require ldap-user .....
</Location>
```